# Why do I get a vector subscript out of range error here?

Tags: c++, vector

i am creating a somekind of rpg battle, where the program reads the input from a .txt file. i created the code but when i want to start the battle, it gave me an error vector subscript out of range. can anyone help me how to fix this? thank you very much :) here is the code. I included everything just so you could get a full context but the main problem I believe is in my while loop in the main cpp, if you want to just skip down to there.

and so that we are on the same track, the content of the txt file for lamanite(hitpoints and regen points) is

```
8 2

7 3

6 1
```

for nephite its

```
10 3

12 4

11 5
```

here is my warrior.h file

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class warrior
{
public:

    warrior ();
    warrior (int h, int r);
    int getDamage() const;
    void takeDamage(int damage);
    int getCurrentHP() const;
    void regenerate();
    string tostring(int h, int r);

private:
    int HitPoints;
    int RegPoints;
    int damage;


};
```

here is my warrior cpp

```
#include "warrior.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

warrior::warrior(int h, int r)
{
    HitPoints = h;
    RegPoints = r;
}

int warrior::getDamage() const
{
    int damage = rand () % HitPoints;
    return damage;
}

void warrior::takeDamage(int damage)
{
    HitPoints = HitPoints - damage;
}

int warrior::getCurrentHP() const
{
    return HitPoints;
}

void warrior::regenerate() 
{
    HitPoints = HitPoints + rand () % (RegPoints);
}

string warrior::tostring(int h, int r)
{
    return 0;
}
```

my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

#include "warrior.h"

using namespace std;

void main ()
{
    srand(time(0));
    ifstream input1;
    cout << "input file name nephite: ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;

    input1.open(filename);

    int HP1, RP1;
    vector <warrior*> nephites;

    while (input1 >> HP1 >> RP1)
    {
        nephites.push_back(new warrior(HP1, RP1));
    }

    cout << nephites.size() << endl;

    ifstream input2;
    cout << "input file name lamanite : ";
    string filename2;
    cin >> filename2;

    input2.open(filename2);
    int HP2, RP2;
    vector <warrior*> lamanites;

    while (input2 >> HP2 >> RP2)
    {
        lamanites.push_back(new warrior(HP2, RP2));
    }
    cout << lamanites.size() << endl;

    cout << endl << "Battle" << endl;

    warrior nephitesw  = warrior (HP1,RP1);
    warrior lamanitesw = warrior (HP2,RP2);

    while ((nephites.size() > 0) && (lamanites.size() > 0))
    {

        int rN = rand () % nephites.size();
        int rL = rand () % lamanites.size();
        cout << rN << "xx" << rL << endl; // so that i know what rN and rL is

        while((nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() > 0) && (lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() > 0)) // the program can't execute this part of the code
        {
            nephites[rN]->takeDamage(lamanites[rL]->getDamage());
            lamanites[rL]->takeDamage(nephites[rN]->getDamage());

            if(lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() > 0)
            {
                lamanites[rL]->regenerate();
            }
            else
            {
                lamanites.erase(lamanites.begin() + (rL));
            } 

            if(nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() > 0) 
            {
                nephites[rN]->regenerate();
            } 
            else
            {
                nephites.erase(nephites.begin() + (rN));
            }
        }

        cout << "NEP HP: " << nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() << " " << "LAM HP: " << lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() << endl;
    }

    system ("Pause");
}
```

Comment: `void main` is not a legal signature and you should be using smart pointers.

Comment: Please don't use tags such as [RPG](stackoverflow.com/tags/RPG/info) if you don't know how they are used on this site. Stackoverflow is a site for professional programmers (and others). RPG is a language used almost exclusively by professional programmers. It runs a major percentage of the businesses you take for granted: retailers, hotels, food distributors, municipalities, warehouses, banks, manufacturing, etc, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping until either `nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() <= 0` or `lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() <= 0`. However, whichever one drops to `0` first will be deleted from the `vector`:

```
// ...
{lamanites.erase(lamanites.begin() + (rL));} 

// ...            
{nephites.erase(nephites.begin() + (rN));}
```

If `rN == nephites.size()` or `rN == lamanites.size()` (which will definitely happen when the size is `1` and may randomly happen earlier), this will cause you to index out of the `vector` when you test the loop.

To quickly solve the problem, move the code that removes the `warrior`(s) from the `vector` out of the loop:

```
while((nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() > 0) && (lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() > 0))
{
    nephites[rN]->takeDamage(lamanites[rL]->getDamage());
    lamanites[rL]->takeDamage(nephites[rN]->getDamage());

    if(lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() > 0)
    {
        lamanites[rL]->regenerate();
    }

    if(nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() > 0) 
    {
        nephites[rN]->regenerate();
    } 
}

cout << "NEP HP: " << nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() << " " << "LAM HP: " << lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() << endl;

// *****
// Move the erasures out of the loop
// *****

if(lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() <= 0)
{
    lamanites.erase(lamanites.begin() + (rL));
} 

if(nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() <= 0)
{
    nephites.erase(nephites.begin() + (rN));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a `while` loop that tests for a certain properties of `nephites[rN]`  and `lamanites[rL]`:

```
while((nephites[rN]->getCurrentHP() > 0) && (lamanites[rL]->getCurrentHP() > 0)
{
    // ...
}
```

But inside that loop you might erase those elements:

```
{lamanites.erase(lamanites.begin() + (rL));} 

// ...

{nephites.erase(nephites.begin() + (rN));}
```

At the very least, after one of those erase operations you'll be testing a different nephite or lamanite object on the next loop iteration (which may or may not be what you want), but if you've erased the last element in the container, you have the problem that the index is now out of range.